# Copying formulas, macros, headings.. but not data

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

I created bookkeeping spreadsheets for 2013.
I want everything copied for working in 2014, but I don't want the data.

I suppose I could go through everything and make sure that it's Protected, then copy, then delete everything?

If I save the 2013 file as a template, will it also save the data entered?
If I create a new workbook from an existing workbook, does it copy everything? or just the protected stuff.

Comment: How is it protected? If I understand you, you want to copy some of the *values* (headers and whatnot) and all of the *formulas*?

Comment: Sounds like a good time to make templates for those workbooks. You could just save as a different name and clear the 2013 data from the files.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a copy of the workbook and run this small macro:

```
Sub DataCleaner()
For Each s In Sheets
    s.Activate
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        v = r.Value
        If (Not r.HasFormula) And IsNumeric(r) Then
            r.ClearContents
        End If
    Next r
Next s
End Sub
```

all the numeric data in the workshets will be removed.